# JSF How to set file name back to original?

Tags: java, file, jsf-2

I'm having problem setting filename back after I create temporary file. I have tried to use `File.renameTo()` but it didn't work. Here is a code that saves my file.

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event){
    uploadedFile = event.getFile();
    Path folder = Paths.get("E:/ProjectUsers/" + loggedUser.getUser().getEmail());
    int indexOfDot = uploadedFile.getFileName().indexOf(".");
    String filename = uploadedFile.getFileName().substring(0,
            indexOfDot);

    String extension = uploadedFile.getFileName().substring(indexOfDot+1);
    try {
        InputStream input = uploadedFile.getInputstream();
        Path file = Files.createTempFile(folder, filename + "-", "." + extension);
        Files.copy(input,file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Success!",  "File has been uploaded"));
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Ooops!",  e.getMessage()));
    }

}
```

After the file is created using `File.createTempFile()` file has some digits attached and I don't know how to get rid of them. It is important to keep original name for me because later the filePath is added to database for later use.
For example lets say the file name I upload is abc.png , after the upload in the folder I get the file named abc-2480631562559339564.png

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're seeing?  The filename shouldn't have extra digits in it based on the code you've shown.  However, what if the file doesn't have a dot in it?

Comment: I've added how it looks